# %iの中にコメントを書く方法は？

Tags: ruby

**ソース**

```
hoge = %i(
  #コメント1
  a
  #コメント2
  b c
  #コメント3
  d
)

p hoge
```

**結果**

> [:"#コメント1", :a, :"#コメント2", :b, :c, :"#コメント3", :d]

`%i`の中にコメントを書く方法はありますか？

Comment: `hoge = %i(...).select{|x| !x.to_s.start_with?("#")}` とするとか。

Comment: 基本％記法の中にコメント（無視される要素）を書くことは無理じゃないかな。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

あるかないかで言うと、「ない」が答えになります。

%記法ではなく、`[ ]` を使うのが最善でしょう。

```
hoge = [
  #コメント1
  :a,
  #コメント2
  :b, :c,
  #コメント3
  :d
]
```

以下のように無理矢理コメントのように扱う方法も考えられますが、`#`の後ろにスペースが入ると意図しない動きになるのでオススメできません。

```
hoge = %i(
  #コメント1
  a
  #コメント2
  b c
  #コメント3
  d
)
hoge.select{|s| s !~ /^#/}
```

参考サイト： [%記法](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/2.3.0/doc/spec=2fliteral.html#symbol)